# how to track IP address from which mail has been sent?

Tags: email, forensics, email-spoofing

I am from India.
I have get few mails from some random Gmail ID. 
How to get the information from which IP address it has been sent ?

Answer (score 3):

The traditional method is to check the email's header for the IP address of the sendeer. But, unfortunately, GMail email headers do not contain the IP address of the sender , so you have no way to check that information even programmatically.

Comment: Is that ? Dont you think by requesting Gmail we can track the IP ?  means how it can be possible that gmail doesn't store any IP from where Mail has been sent ?

Comment: @user1650894 In the past, GMail stores the IP address of the sender in the email's header, but that is no longer the case. Why it is no longer the case? Ask Google support for that.

Comment: @user1650894 Storing and showing it to the user are two fundamentally different things ;)

Comment: Ya, Exactly, @SleepProggger thats what I am saying... I want to get the IP address.

Comment: @user1650894 You will need either to hack Google or take a lawyer to get it.